# How to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS with __set() method?

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

I want to create an object right after fetching data from my database.

For that I'm using PDO::FETCH_CLASS and a rewritten __set() method that I've put in a trait.

However, I can't figure out why I have an error mentionning : 
"Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Banner::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\projet-4\writer-blog\entity\Banner.php on line 34"

Here is my Banner class (setters and getters omitted) :

```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'\Set.php');
/**
 * This class represents a banner that will be displayed on the homepage of the FrontEnd
 */
class Banner 
{
    use Set;

    protected   $errors=[],
                $id,
                $displayOrder,
                $title,
                $caption,
                $image,
                $buttonTitle,
                $buttonLink,
                $creationDate,
                $modificationDate;

    /**
     * Constants for errors management during the execution of the methods
     */
    const INCORRECT_IMAGE_LINK = 1;
    const INCORRECT_TITLE = 2;
    const INCORRECT_CAPTION = 3;

    /**
     * Class constructor which assign values that have been passed in parameters to matching attributes 
     *
     * @param array $donnees The values to allocate
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->hydrate($data);
    }

    /**
     * Method that allocates specified valued to the matching attributes
     *
     * @param array $donnees The values to allocate
     * @return void
     */
    public function hydrate($data)
    {
      foreach ($data as $key => $value)
      {
        $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
          $this->$method($value);
        }
      }
    }
```

My magical method __set() is in the following Trait :

```php
<?php

trait Set {
    public function __set($property, $value)
    {
        $explodedProperty = explode("_", $property);

        for ($i = 1 ; $i < count($explodedProperty); $i++) {
            ucfirst($explodedProperty[$i]);
        }

        $rightPropertyName = ucfirst(implode($explodedProperty));

        if (property_exists(__CLASS__, $rightPropertyName))
        {
            $this->$rightPropertyName = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('La propriété n\'a pas pu se voir assigner une valeur car elle n\'existe pas!');
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the beggining of my BannerManager where I fetch my data :

```php
<?php 

require_once("model/Manager.php");
require_once("entity/Banner.php");

class BannerManager extends Manager
{
    public function getBanners()
    {
        $db = $this->dbConnect();
        $req = $db->query('SELECT id, title, caption, image, button_title, button_link, 
        DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS creation_date_fr, DATE_FORMAT(modification_date, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS modification_date_fr 
        FROM banners ORDER BY display_order LIMIT 5'); 

        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Banner');

        $banners = $req->fetchAll();

        return $banners;
    }
```

Comment: because exactly 1 argument is expected in `__construct(array $data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual question here is How to use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` with a class that requires constructor parameters as that's what the error message says.

And the answer is [setFetchMode's third parameter.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php).

```
$req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Banner',[[]]);
```

should do the trick, providing an empty array for the constructor, thus letting your code reach the point where `__set()` is actually called.